# reorder array with big dataset (VBA)(exclude some columns)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, datatable

[image]i need a macro to select some objects (rows) of the big database with over 500 rows and copy 12 of the 44 columns into an array and reorder them into an comparison table. I need the column headers reordered  as row headers.

The goal is to export the new ordered comparison table into an existing  powerpoint template.  I will try to not copy the entire columns and just to copy the columns i need.

I'm new to Vba and would appreciate any help.

This is my code for reading the data so far:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Dim Myarray As Variant

Dim LastRow As Integer, LastColumn As Integer

Dim StartCells As Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") Google Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Set StartCell = ws1.Range("A1")

LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

LastColumn = ws1.Cells(StartCell.Row,ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Answer (score 1):

My fake dataset is like this:

[image]

You said *I need the column headers reordered as row headers.* so you need to transpose.

In my code I'm using columns 2,5,6 and 8 but you can change this easily.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Myarray() As Variant
Dim LastRow As Integer, LastColumn As Integer
Dim StartCell As Range
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set StartCell = ws1.Range("A1")
LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = ws1.Cells(StartCell.Row, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'copy specific columns into worksheet 2

j = 1
For i = 1 To LastColumn Step 1
    Select Case i
        Case 2, 5, 6, 8 'target columns to copy
            With ws1
                Myarray() = .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(LastRow, i)).Value
            End With
            
            With ws2
                .Range(.Cells(j, 1), .Cells(j, LastRow)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Myarray())
            End With
            j = j + 1
        Case Else
    End Select
Next i

Erase Myarray()

End Sub
```

Output I get:

[image]

Comment: You should open a new question about that issue.